# Где можно почитать про tc

Tags: сеть, tc, трафик, linux

Интересуют в первую очередь именно мануалы. А то по ссылкам из поиска захожу, а там "для примера рассмотрим ..." а мне бы не для примера а полностью и статьёй, а не как в man-ах

Answer (score 1):

> Интересуют в первую очередь именно мануалы
>
> а не как в man-ах

Не очень понял, что хотите, в любом случае посоветовал бы  [Traffic-Control-HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/)

Comment: Спасибо, в принципе оно, но хотелось бы по русски и с коментариями. И мнно это я имел ввиду, когда говорил про статью

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/LARTC/LARTC-net.html.gz

Answer (score 0):

Тут ребята уже что-то советовали, но похоже, надо начинать "ab ovo". То есть, с самого начала. А это вот тут: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model